# TableCellEditor for multiple columns

Tags: java, swing

I am wanting to use a cell editor and a `DocumentFilter` to prevent the user from entering certain characters into the table cells.

The columns are as follows:

- Product ID
- Product Description
- Inventory Count
- Cost
- Minimum Quantity

For Inventory Count, Cost and Minimum Quantity I am going to use a `JFormattedTextField`.

How can this be improved?

```
public class ProductTableCellEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor
{

    private TableCellEditor editor;

    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue()
    {
    if (editor != null) {
        return editor.getCellEditorValue();
    }
    return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column)
    {
    JTextField textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setFont(ApplicationStyles.TABLE_FONT);

    switch (column)
    {
    case 0:
        ((AbstractDocument) textField.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new ProductTableDocumentFilter());
        editor = new DefaultCellEditor(textField);
        break;
    case 1:
        ((AbstractDocument) textField.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new ProductTableDocumentFilter());
        editor = new DefaultCellEditor(textField);
        break;
    case 2:
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet supported....");
    case 3:
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet supported....");
    case 4:
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet supported....");
    default:
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet supported....");
    }
    return editor.getTableCellEditorComponent(table, value, isSelected, row, column);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(AbstractDocument) textField.getDocument()
```

This is bad practice.

I recommend that you do one of these options:

- The simple way would be to create a method `toAbstractDocument(Document document)`
- The better way would be to create a field at `TextField` class such as `? extends Document document`.

Comment: I am confused on how to get this to work.....

Comment: I tried this:        class TextField <T extends Document>            but it won't work because setDocumentFilter is of abstractDocument and not document. I would still have to cast in a method to get this to work. I could do something like this: doc = (AbstractDocument) textField.getDocument;   Is that bad practice?